# polymorphic boost::allocate_unique

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism, unique-ptr

is it possible to use boost::allocate_unique function released boost in 1.72 with polymorphism ? or is there any workaround to use allocate_unique with polymorphism?

I mean mechanism like make_unique we used in the standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/allocate_unique.hpp>
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {

    }

};

class Der : public Base
{
public:

};

class Der2 : public Base
{
public:

};


int main ()
{
    boost::pool_allocator<Base> pool;

    std::unique_ptr<Base, alloc_deleter<Base, decltype (pool)>> uptr = boost::allocate_unique<Der>(pool);

    std::unique_ptr<Base, alloc_deleter<Base, decltype (pool)>> uptr2 = boost::allocate_unique<Der2>(pool);

}
```